# Change Vim Background Text Color for transparent terminal

Tags: vim, colors, background

I'm currently learning to use vim as my main editor, I really like to have a transparent terminal where I can do all my work and not loose focus of what I'm doing, because of this, I was trying to find a way to have background only on the text when I open a file using vim (as if it was highlighted)

My terminal currently looks like this:

[image: It is entirely transparent]

and I want to achieve to have it looking like this:
(Edit) My terminal currently is not looking like this, I just highlighted everything to show how I wanted it to look*

[image: Just for the text, not the whole background, can be a solid color]

(Edit) Note: the background color just for the text not for the entire line

So far I tried using different themes (I stuck with material since is the one I use in VSCODE) and also changing

```
hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE
```

to maintain the transparency even inside vim but I couldn't find a way where I can just change the background color of the text, all the solutions I found was to change the full background instead

I'll paste down here my `~/.vim/vimrc` config file:

```
" Predef configs of vim
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set hidden
let $RTP=split(&runtimepath, ',')[0]
let $RC="$HOME/.vim/vimrc"


" Tabs of 3 spaces
set tabstop=3


" List of plugins 
call plug#begin()

Plug 'kaicataldo/material.vim', { 'branch': 'main' }
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript', { 'branch': 'master' }

call plug#end()


" Material theme reqs and colorscheme
if (has('termguicolors'))
  set termguicolors
endif

colorscheme material

" Overwrite transparent background for matherial theme
hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE
```

thanks for the help in advance! :)

Comment: You say "I want to achieve to have it looking like this" immediately followed by a screenshot of what you want to achieve so… it looks like you already have your problem solved, no?

Comment: I left a description of the images in the link, seems like Stackoverflow replaced the links with the actual file, the second file is just me highliting the text on the terminal to show how I want it to be

Comment: So you want to change the background color of the text OR of the full line?

Comment: The background color of the text only